# Kotlin: user input into list

Tags: android, list, kotlin, user-input, adapter

**I'm trying to create an app in Android Studio, where the user needs to input multiple names that are going to be stored in a list.** I also wish to show the list to the users with ListView.

Right now my approach is to have an EditText container where the user can input text, and then with the press of a button it would add it to the list "AllPlayersHidden". From there it would update the adapter, and then the ListView.

Here's the main functional snippet:

```
        // List of players that is shown
        val AllPlayers = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.AllPlayers)
        AllPlayers.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this) //adapter telling listview what to show


        // Hidden list
        val AllPlayersHidden = mutableListOf<String>()

        // Button to input name into list
        val AddPlayer = findViewById<Button>(R.id.AddPlayer)
        AddPlayer.setOnClickListener {
            AllPlayersHidden.add(AddPlayer.getText().toString())
```

And here's the full adapter:

```
private class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context): BaseAdapter() {

        private val mContext: Context

        init {
            this.mContext = context
        }

        //responsible for amount of rows in list
        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return 5
        }

        // you can also ignore this
        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        // you can ignore this for now
        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return "TEST STRING"
        }

        // responsioble for rendering out each row
        override fun getView(p0: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View {
            val textView = TextView(mContext)
            textView.text =
            return textView
        }
```

**What do I still need to do, to get it to work?**

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use a simple ArrayAdpter and remove you CustomAdapter

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
         R.layout.activity_listview, AllPlayersHidden. toTypedArray());
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does and how does it differ from the custom adapter?

Comment: the custom adapter you've written probably leads to a memory leak. If you want to build a simple list with an array of data, you'd better use this ArrayAdapter.

Comment: the custom adapter you've written probably leads to a memory leak. If you want to build a simple list with an array of data, you'd better use this ArrayAdapter.